# Reverting back to previous push in Netbeans with Git

Tags: git, netbeans, version-control

In a project I committed and pushed changes to a repo. Then I made some changes to the source code that I would like to undo. What's the best way of accomplishing this? Is just a pull enough?

Somethings that concern me: if I pull will I be given the chance to leave some sort of message, like when I commit? I think it would be good to leave a reason for why the direction I was heading in wouldn't work. Also, does git operate per file or on the whole project? For example if I made changes to two files should I commit AND push them separately?

In general I struggle a lot with finding a productive workflow with Git.

Comment: Have a look at git revert.

Comment: Please show us the exact steps you took here.  Depending on what you did, you may just be able to handle this locally, without involving the repo.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I committed and then pushed. Then I made changes to the source code (which I regret) so now would like to undo them and go back to what's on the server. Does this answer what you were asking? I did all of this through the menu options in Netbeans.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to go back to the state of the last commit you made to the current branch, then try doing a hard reset to HEAD:

```
git reset --hard HEAD
```

Note that this will completely wipe out all the changes both in your working directory *and* stage, so you should use this command with serious discretion.

A safer thing to do might be to just `git checkout -- <path/to/some/file>` for each file you modified.

Comment: You would execute them from the Git bash, which is a program which can be found in the `bin` directory of your Git folder (wherever you installed it).

Comment: Would this affect all files or just one? How would I do it to affect just one?

Comment: Is `<path/to/some/file>` the local or remote file? It doesn't make sense to me how both don't need to be specified.